# Lens - What happened to traverseInit?

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens

In early versions [`Data.List.Lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-3.3/docs/Data-List-Lens.html) there was a function `traverseInit` that was used to manipulate parts of lists. It has been removed, and I assume there is an alternative to this now but I can't quite find it?

how would I do something like

```
>>> traverseInit +~ 1 $ [1,2,3]
[2,3,3]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`traverseInit` got replaced with the more general [`_init :: Snoc s s a a => Traversal' s s`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html#v:_init) from [`Control.Lens.Cons`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html), so now it works with any sequence-like type which allows access to its right-hand end.

```
ghci> [1,2,3] & _init.traverse +~ 1
[2,3,3]
```

Note that `_init` returns a `Traversal' s s`, not a `Traversal' s a`, allowing you to replace the whole sublist, possibly changing its length. In the example I had to `traverse` again to look at the elements. (`_init` happens to be an *affine* traversal, meaning it'll never return more than one sublist, but that is not expressible in `lens`'s vocabulary.)

`Control.Lens.Cons` includes an analogous traversal of a list's [`_tail`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html#v:_tail), as well as traversals of a list's [`_head`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html#v:_head) and [`_last`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens-4.16.1/docs/Control-Lens-Cons.html#v:_last).